# sql server create pivot from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|      Period         |     Calorie      |Tonnage   |product |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|     2020-01-01      |       4989       |110000    |E5000   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|     2020-02-01      |       5200       |120000    |E5000   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|     2020-03-01      |       7000       |130000    |E5000   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
```

and I the expected output is like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|      Info           |     Jan          |Feb       |March   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|     E5000           |       110000     |120000    |130000  |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
|     Calorie         |       4989       |5200      |7000    |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|--------|
```

I am able to flat out single column using pivot, but I don't know how to pivot more than one column and produce result like expected above. below is my current query

```
select  * from (
select
    a.[Product], 
    a.Tonnage,
    LEFT( DATENAME(MONTH, [Period]) ,3) as MLM 
   from 
    [ProductionData] a 
   Where 
    DATEPART(YEAR,a.[Period]) = 2019) PS
   PIVOT 
    (AVG (Tonnage) for MLM in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])) PVT
```

please advice, Thanks

Comment: you can refer : [sql server dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: What if there is a row with `E6000` ?

Comment: @Serg it will also have one calorie row below E6000,

Comment: There is no such think as "row below the row" in the sql world.  You need an explicit `order by <set of columns> ` to have rows odered. And i see no way to order the result as it is. Consider a result schema `Product, Info,Jan,Feb,March`  where `Info` values in  `Calorie,Tonnage `.

Answer (score 3):

One way is simply a `UNION ALL` of two queries in the source query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT
    [Product] AS Info,
    LEFT( DATENAME(MONTH, [Period]) ,3) AS MLM,
    Tonnage AS Val
   FROM [ProductionData]
   WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, [Period]) = 2019

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
    'Calorie' AS Info,
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [Period]) ,3) AS MLM,
    Calorie AS Val
   FROM [ProductionData]
   WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, [Period]) = 2019
) SRC
PIVOT (
   AVG (Val) 
   FOR MLM in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
) PVT
```

Or replace such `UNION ALL` by a `CROSS APPLY` to values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT
    ca.Info,
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, t.[Period]) ,3) AS MLM,
    ca.Val
   FROM [ProductionData] t
   CROSS APPLY(VALUES (t.[Product], t.Tonnage),('Calorie', t.Calorie)) ca(Info, Val)
   WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, t.[Period]) = 2019
) SRC
PIVOT (
   AVG (Val) 
   FOR MLM in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
) PVT
```